# I am trying to write a python program to find a prime number

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are many ways to do this but I want to do it specifically using the code below:

```
"""
Find the number is prime or not
"""

num =100
print(f"{num} is{' not a' if num%2==0 else 'not a' if num%x==0 else 'a' for x in range(3,(num//2)+1,2)} Prime Number")
```

I get the following output:

```
100 is<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001A5E440F0F8> Prime Number
```

Comment: Below is the error :
100 is<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001A5E440F0F8> Prime Number

Comment: That is not an error, it is the output of your `print` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a generator object in your `f-string` formatting.

You can get literal value by using `str`s `join` method
Replace your `f-string` formatting with :

```
print(f"{num} is{''.join({' not a' if num%2==0 else 'not a' if num%x==0 else 'a' for x in range(3,(num//2)+1,2)})}  Prime Number")
```

Output:

```
100 is not a  Prime Number
```

Comment: @beer44 This will print out both `not a` and `a` often for non-primes. Try `num=35`.

Comment: @uneven_mark that's the logic he implemented. my solution clarify to the getting the value from generator object in `f-string` formatting.

Comment: @beer44 If you didn't want to fix the logic, why did you add the set, i.e. `join({...})` instead of `join(...)`? With the set it *seems* to work for some numbers, while the logic error would have been obvious without it.